# useEffect has a missing dependency: 'user'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a certain query string I am looking for and when that gets passed on page loading I need to update my user's status to "premium". I have:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const queryString = require('query-string');
    const values = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
    console.log('before' + user.premium);
    if (values.premium !== ''){
      setUser({...user, premium: true});
    }
    console.log('after' + user.premium);
  }, []);
```

I am using React functional components and my user is an object that contains many other values, in addition to "premium" key. From what I understand, passing the empty array `[]` will cause useEffect to run only on page load. Doing so, however, I get an error:

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'user'.`. BUT, when I include `user` in that array, the page continually reloads (since I am updating the value of it). I've also tried passing in `setUser` and that didn't work.

Comment: `setUser(prevUser => ({ ...prevUser, premium: true }))`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts can you please school me - what's the theory behind y'all high reppers sometimes commenting answers instead of actually submitting as an answer?

Comment: @Rustang Answered trivial variations of this exact same question several times already... still trying to find one of the duplicates to close with.

Comment: @Rustang It's also sometimes significantly easier to provide enough info in a comment that may solve the problem, but would be an incomplete or poor answer on its own.

Comment: But a complete answer is always best to help future people who may implement comments poorly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Okay cool I see, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @DaveNewton Alright nice, this was closer to my hunch so thanks for the input!

Comment: Took long enough but I finally found some decent duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass properties of object as dependencies for `useEffect`. I have created a working [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-boyd-2pr51?file=/src/App.js:0-772).

Also, don't worry to much about the eslint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`, view it as more of a guideline and don't be afraid to add a `eslint-disable-next-line` if it is pushing you to add dependencies that you don't think should be added.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ count: 0, premium: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("when component mounts");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("when component updates");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("when premium changes");
  }, [user.premium]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {user.count}</p>
      <p>Premium: {user.premium}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => setUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, count: prev.count + 1 }))}
      >
        Increment Count
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => setUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, premium: !prev.premium }))}
      >
        Toggle premium
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, ignoring the eslint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` will usually lead to subtle bugs due to stale references being kept. There's always a way to satisfy the exhaustive dependencies, even if it's sometimes a little more verbose than you might like.

Comment: With all due respect, unit tests are better at discovering dependency errors than a linter. Making code overly verbose to appease a linter can harm readability and maintainability of code without actually providing a great deal of confidence.